# How to reload MaxScale cache rules without restarting the service?

Tags: mariadb, maxscale

I'm looking for a way to apply a new set of rules in /etc/maxscale.rules (JSON) as specified as rules=/etc/maxscale.rules in my cnf file, without restarting the entire MaxScale service.

I am not seeing a MaxAdmin setting that allows manipulating of Cache Filters, but perhaps there is another way?

I also note that a service 'reload' parameter is not implemented, only a service stop/start/restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache filter rules cannot be reloaded in the current MaxScale version. You can submit feature requests on the [MariaDB Jira under the MaxScale project](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS).

You can work around this limitation by [creating](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-23-maxctrl/#create-filter) a new filter, [replacing](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-23-maxctrl/#alter-service-filters) the original filter with the new one and [destroying](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-23-maxctrl/#destroy-filter) the old one.